# Is there an in-built function that gets the names of datatype entries?

Tags: function, isabelle

I'd just like to know if it is possible to get the name of a datatype entry in Isabelle. For example:

```
datatype Test = A int | B string | C nat
```

Is there a function (call it `f` for now) that does the following?

```
f(A 5) = A
f(B ''hi'') = B
f(C 234789623) = C
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I know, nothing of the sort exists. What problem are you trying to solve? (i.e. why do you need this?)

Comment: Are you talking about a function in Isabelle/ML or Isabelle/HOL? Also, what is meant by "the name"? What type should "the name" have?

Comment: The major issue is the type: your function does not type! For such kind of things you need Coq/Lean where you a term type for such cases.